# unable to trigger window.open on js code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Im having issues with .js codes. the window.open seems to be not working. i have tried using window.location and not working also. Can anyone suggest what could be the fix for this?

Here's the code that im currently using

```
if ("web page" == $scope.model.ComponentModel.Screen.trnscntype) {
                    var staffId = ichrisCache.get("loginStaffNumber");

                    if ($scope.model.ComponentModel.FormCode == 'SEL') {
                        var menulinkParameters = { staffId: staffId, formCode: $scope.model.ComponentModel.FormCode };

                        $scope.retLink = "";

                        var menuLinks = SelfServiceLinkURL.query(menulinkParameters,
                            function (output) {
                                $scope.retLink = output;
                                console.log($scope.retLink);
                                alert('inside menulinks');
                            });
                        alert('outside menulinks');
                        window.location.href = $scope.retLink;
                        //window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        window.open($scope.model.ComponentModel.Screen.urlwebpage);
                    }

                }
```

although the $scope.retLink can be logged on console.log but when i placed it inside the window.open($scope.retLink); it is not triggering.

Suggestions and inputs are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of $scope.model.ComponentModel.Screen.urlwebpage at the point when you call window.open? Use the console debugging, or add console.log($scope.model.ComponentModel.Screen.urlwebpage) in your code right about your window.open.

Comment: `$scope.retLink = output;` Seems like this assignment is corrupting desired value. Check what is toString value of retLink.